# Solving $\frac{dh}{dt} = Ch^{\delta}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the ODE below,

$$\frac{dh}{dt} = Ch^{\delta}$$

where $C>0$ is a constant, and $\delta>1$ is as well. The solution is given as

$$ h(t) = \bigg( \frac{h_0}{t_c - t} \bigg)^\alpha $$

where $\alpha = \frac{1}{\delta-1}$

I was not able to derive this; I did

$$
\int \frac{dh}{h^{\delta}} = C \int dt
$$

$$
\frac{h(t)^{-\delta+1}}{-\delta+1} = Ct+C_2
$$

I am stuck at this point, how do I get cleanly $h_0$ in this equation, and  what would the main direction for the derivation be?

The equation comes from [this paper](https://kr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/12237/frolova-paper-15.pdf), pg 5.

Comment: Just apply the condition $h(t_c)=h_0$ to get $C_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $C_2$ as a constant of integration, let's use $-Ct_c$.  Then your last equation can be re-written as
$$\frac{h(t)^{-\delta+1}}{-\delta+1} = C(t-t_c)$$
which can be re-written as
$$h(t)^{1-\delta} = (1-\delta)C(t-t_c)$$
Raise both side to the $-\alpha = \frac{1}{1-\delta}$ power to obtain
$$h(t) = \{(1-\delta)C(t-t_c)\}^{-\alpha}$$
Then factor the exponent on right side into $(-1)(\alpha)$ to get
$$h(t) = \left(\frac{(1-\delta)^{-1}C^{-1}}{(t-t_c)}\right)^{\alpha}$$
Now claim that $h_0=-(1-\delta)^{-1}C^{-1}=(\delta-1)^{-1}C^{-1}$ to obtain
$$h(t) = \left(\frac{h_0}{t_c-t}\right)^{\alpha}$$
Usually we use the symbol $h_0$ in place of $h(0)$, but here that is clearly not the case.